# How to solve AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rhs' while solving differential equation using python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

```
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x,y=symbols('x y', real =True)
M=5*x*sqrt(x)+7*y**2/sqrt(x)
N=28*y*sqrt(x)
if diff(M,y) == diff(N,x):
    print("The equation is exact")
else:
    print("The equation is not Exact")
y=Function('y')
deq=(5*x*sqrt(x)+7*y(x)**2/sqrt(x))+(28*y(x)*sqrt(x))*diff(y(x),x)
ysoln=dsolve(deq,y(x),hint='1st_exact',ics={y(1):1})
print("The solution of the given differential equation is:")
pprint(ysoln)
plt.plot(ysoln.rhs, (x,-2,2))
```

this is the python program for solving a differential equation deq. but while running this code it shows attribute error.

I tried changing the values and changing the equation

Comment: What version of SymPy are you using? I suggest updating to the latest (1.11).

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to update SymPy to the latest version (1.11).

Then, `plt.plot` doesn't know how to deal with sympy objects. Hence you need to use sympy's `plot`. So, you have to modify the last line code to this:

```
plot(ysoln.rhs, (x,-2,2))
```

Comment: I'm using anaconda as my code editor and in anaconda it requires 1.10.1 version of sympy and I am not able to update sympy.